# Erlang handling errors in concurrent programs

Tags: error-handling, child-process, erlang

I have two tasks:

> Write a function that starts and monitors several worker processes. If any of the worker processes dies abnormally, restart it

Here is the code that I built:

```
proc() -> 
    receive 
        p -> exit("I need to die")
    end.


start_and_monitor(0) -> 
    spawn_monitor(proc()),
    receive 
        {'DOWN',_,process,_,_} -> spawn_monitor(proc())
    end;
start_and_monitor(Int) -> 

    spawn_monitor(proc()),
    start_and_monitor(Int - 1).
```

> Write a function that starts and monitors several worker processes. If any of the worker processes dies abnormally, kill all the worker processes and restart them all.

Here I thought that instead of monitoring all of the process I could link all the small processes and monitor a major process that is linked to all of them. Here is the code:

```
start_and_monitor_but_kill(Int) ->
{Pid,Ref} = spawn_monitor(start_monitor_kill(Int)),
receive
    {'DOWN', Ref, process, _, _} -> start_and_monitor_but_kill(Int)
end.


start_monitor_kill(0) ->
    spawn_link(proc());
start_monitor_kill(Int) ->
    spawn_link(proc()),
    start_monitor_kill(Int-1).
```

Is there any way that I can improve my code? Am I using all the erlang primitives correctly ? Any criticism is highly appreciated.

Also I am very curious if I used the primitives correctly. For example I used the monitor process without giving a ref. Is this acceptable in this case?

Comment: This code is not valid. see the definition of `spawn_link/1`, and `spawn_monitor/1` at [erlang doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're calling `spawn_monitor/1` like this:

```
spawn_monitor(proc()),
```

where `proc/0` is a local function, but this doesn't do what you think it does. First it calls `proc/0`, which blocks in a `receive` until it gets a message. Normally it would return the value of `receive`, but your `receive` calls `exit/1` so there's no return. So, what happens is that the first call into `proc/0` blocks until it receives a message, at which point it exits, and since it was running not in a spawned process but in the calling process — *the process where the caller is running* — the caller exits too. Nothing ever gets spawned or monitored. (This same problem exists in your second code example too.)

What `spawn_monitor/1` wants is a function, so you should be calling it like this:

```
spawn_monitor(fun proc/0),
```

If you make that change everywhere, then the code works, but there's one other thing: your `start_and_monitor(0)` function clause should not be calling `spawn_monitor` before calling `receive`, otherwise `Int+1` rather than `Int` processes will be spawned and monitored.

As for the second code example, monitors and processes are cheap, so there's no point in trying to bundle them together into a single monitoring point.

And finally, you might consider solving this problem not with monitors but rather with links. A monitor allows a process to watch an unrelated process, but if one process is spawning another, then they're related, so links are a viable approach.